# specify a maximum Value for a UITextField in Swift

Tags: swift

I need to specify a maximum value for a text field. I already got an answer from another post on how to restrict a UITextField to numbers only. But I would like to modify that function to only accept a number between 0 and 540.

Is there any way to modify that function?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
  let s = NSString(string: textField.text ?? "").replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
  guard !s.isEmpty else { return true }
  let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
  numberFormatter.numberStyle = .none
  return numberFormatter.number(from: s)?.intValue != nil
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    print(string)
    let myRange = 0...540
    
    //ro delete/remove values in textField
    if string == "" {
        return true
    }

    let fullText = NSString(string: textField.text ?? "").replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    
    if let wholeNumber = Int(fullText), myRange.contains(wholeNumber) {
        return true
    }
    
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if number lies between 0 and 540.

```
if let number = numberFormatter.number(from: s)?.intValue {
 return number > 0 && number < 540  
} else {
 return true 
}
```